# Which ions do not react with each other in a solution?

Tags: ions

> Which ions do not react with each other in solution?
>
> A. $Ba^{2+},SO_4^{2-},NO_3^-$
>
> B. $Cu^{2+},SO_4^{2-},OH^-$
>
> C. $Ag^+,Cl^-,H^+$
>
> D. $K^+,Fe^{3+},Br^-$

I have no idea why the answer is **D**. Please help.

Comment: Do you have any other information to draw upon as to why you think it might not be some of the other choices?

Comment: The answer by @Daniel is closest to the truth. Each of A, B, and C will produce an insoluble *participate*, which will fall out of solution, as he notes.  In answer D, bromide ion forms an ionic compound with both potassium ion and ferric ion, which are soluble and so nothing precipitates out of solution.

Comment: I believe you mean _precipitate_?

Comment: @jonsca http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9912229#9912229

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the question is slightly misleading, non of the ions *react* however some do *precipitate*.

BaSO<sub>4</sub>, Cu(OH)<sub>2</sub> , and AgCl will precipitate in A, B, and C respectively.

Comment: How is Ag$^+$ + Cl$^-$ $\to$ AgCl not a reaction?

Answer (score 0):

The question (and its choices) are bogus. One can make species (and solutions) of all of these combinations of cations with anions.